# Linux support for wifi drivers Ubit WIE7265 and xUbuntu 20.04.1

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu, iwlwifi

This is my first time posting so apologies if the format isn't quite right, but I am looking for some help in installing drivers for a Ubit PCI network card I recently installed in my computer. (The card in question is here: http://www.evisionde.com/prodetail.aspx?ProID=86)

I've managed to get the card working using the drivers from the above link but gives low upload and download speeds, and low signal strength. I noticed that although the download folder was titled "WIE7265 Linux 4.2+", the folder actually contains "iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode", and not 7265 drivers as I'd expect. Could this in some way be related to the poor performance of this card?

Does anybody know of any workarounds or potential fixes I could apply, before I go ahead and look for a more compatible card? Any suggestions around this would also be greatly appreciated! I'm under the impression intel AX200 chips seem to work well with linux systems.

Thanks,
Solaria

Comment: The driver iwlwifi and the required frmware, which is what is actually downloadable at the site you linked, have been included by default in all recent versions of Ubuntu. In fact, the default firmware is the newer -17 version, not the -13 that is hosted at the linked site. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.